# How to store datatable into json object variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, datatables

I have a datatable in javascript, which is generated depending on user input.

```
var dtable = $('.ssdatatable').DataTable({
    "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, 100, 500], [10, 25, 50, 100, 500]],
    "bProcessing": true,
    "sDom": "TBflrtip",
    "bServerSide": true,
    "sAjaxSource": ajSource,
    "iDisplayLength": 25,
    "bJqueryUI": false,
    //"bJqueryUI": true,
    "bAutoWidth": false,
    "recordsFiltered": 0,
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "bPaginate": true,
    "sServerMethod": "POST",
    "responsive": true,
    "fixedHeader": true,

    "aoColumns": [
      { "mData": "variable" },
      //other columns
    ],
    "fnServerData": function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback, oSettings) {
        aoData.push({ 'name': 'AreaIdsInput', 'value': $("#AreaIdsInput").val() });
        //push other parameters
        oSettings.jqXHR = $.ajax({
            "dataType": 'json',
            "type": "POST",
            "url": sSource,
            "data": aoData,
            "success": fnCallback
        });
    }
```

What I want is to store results of generated table into an object, so I can access parameters and its values for a future use.

Upon research and talking to other programmers, I have found that there should be a method to store generated datatable into a json object variable. However, I was not able to locate the method through the further research.

Unless I mistake it for the oSettings.jqXHR section, **what is the method to store the instance of generated datatable into a json object variable?**

## UPDATE

Now that I think about it, I should mention that I am working with a combination of C# and Javascript, so maybe my question relates not only to Javascript but there is also the way to do it in C# (like using it in controller or something?)

Comment: `JSON.stringify(yourObject)` return your object as string (valid json) and then you can parse it back to an object using `JSON.parse(yourJSONString)`.

Comment: Could [this](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/state_save.html) help you?